# Totally distance non-preserving transformations

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, extremal-combinatorics, metric-embeddings

JL lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) 
 guarantees if you have a set of $K$ points in $\Bbb R^N$ a random transformation guarantees that the set can be projected to $\Bbb R^n$ where $n\ll N$ without much distortion as long as $n_0<n$ for some $n_0$ that depends on distortion and $K$.

Here we seek a related problem.

Fix $n',N$ with $N<n'$ and $K$.

Pick a set of $K$ points with minimum pairwise distance $d$ and maximum pairwise distance $D$ in $\Bbb R^N$ around origin then 'typically' is there an $f_{n',K}(m)$ monotone decreasing function we can have such that there is a single linear transformation that maps pairwise distances $m$ to distances pairwise distances ${f_{n',K}(m)}$ apart in $\Bbb R^{n'}$ holds?